# Obtener fechas con mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema, quiero recuperar de forma dinámica lo que pasó hace siete días, y después lo que pasó hace seis, cinco y así hasta hace 1 día.
El problema esta en que cuando hago between de la fecha acumula los datos, no me trae lo que pasó exactamente 7 días si no que me trae el acumulado de estos 7 días.

```
for ($i=7; $i > 0; $i--)
    {
        $q = "select count(*) as cnt, 'promedio' as col
                    from oreData.events
                    where evt_listener <> $prop_id
                    and evt_date between now() - interval $i day and now()
                    union
                    select count(*) as cnt, evt_listener as col
                    from oreData.events
                    where evt_listener = $prop_id
                    and evt_date between now() - interval $i day and now()";
}
```

He intentado filtrarlo con

```
and YEAR(evt_date) = YEAR(NOW())
and MONTH(evt_date) = MONTH(NOW())
and DAY(evt_date) = DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL $i DAY)
```

El problema es que si me encuentro en el día 1 del cualquier mes o el primer día del año ya no se cumple la condición, como arreglo esto

Gracias por las sugerencias

Answer (score 1):

> El problema esta en que cuando hago between de la fecha acumula los
>   datos, no me trae lo que pasó exactamente 7 días si no que me trae el
>   acumulado de estos 7 días.

Estás usando `count(*)` sin agrupar por fecha. En vez de:

```
select count(*) as cnt, 'promedio' as col
from oreData.events
where evt_listener <> $prop_id
and evt_date between now() - interval $i day and now()
```

Debiera ser

```
SELECT evt_date, count(*) as cnt, 'promedio' as col
FROM oreData.events
WHERE evt_listener <> $prop_id
AND evt_date between (now() - INTERVAL $i DAY) AND now()
GROUP BY evt_date
```

(y eso te devolvería todas las filas, día por día, de lo que ha pasado en los últimos `$i` días)

En todo caso, me sorprende que lo que viene después de tu `UNION` no provoque un error. Debiera ser, entonces:

```
SELECT evt_date, count(*) as cnt, 'promedio' as col
FROM oreData.events
WHERE evt_listener <> $prop_id
AND evt_date between (now() - INTERVAL $i DAY) AND now()
GROUP BY evt_date

UNION ALL

SELECT evt_date, count(*) as cnt, $prop_id as col
FROM oreData.events
WHERE evt_listener = $prop_id
AND evt_date BETWEEN (now() - INTERVAL $i DAY) AND now()
GROUP BY evt_date
```

Otra observación: si vas sobreescribiendo la consulta en el bucle `for`, sólo ejecutarás la consulta del último valor de `$i`.

**EDIT**: corrijo error de sintaxis (AND duplicado)

**EDIT2**: creo que sería mejor una sintaxis explícita para el between

Comment: No funciona, he visto varios errores en tu propuesta, Hay un doble "and" en el between, me marca un error al agrupar. No te preocupes por el FOR, despues del SQL hago la ejecución, solo puse el query pues es el que está mal, no la ejecución. Agradezco tu sugerencia.

Comment: Es cierto, se me coló un error de sintaxis. Te agradecería que nos contaras qué error te da al agrupar (la primera consulta) y cuáles son los otros varios errores.

Comment: Oh, veo que cuando reemplacé `and` por `AND` en realidad reemplacé `day`. Por ahí partió todo

Comment: Ya lo ejecuté y me regresa la agrupación por fecha, pero el campo evt_date es de tipo DATETIME, como lo agrupo por fecha pero ignorando la hora, por ejemplo el campo trae: 2017-12-06 12:00:00

Comment: Puedes poner `DATE(evt_date)` tanto en el campo como en el group by

Answer (score 0):

Hola [Alberto Siurob](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/9885/alberto-siurob), prepare un pequeño `sql` que hace todo el trabajo, solo basta ejecutarlo y te arrojará todos los eventos entre la fecha actual y hace 7 días:

```
SELECT *
FROM oreData.events
WHERE DATEDIFF(now(),evt_date) <=7 AND DATEDIFF(now(),evt_date) >0
ORDER BY evt_date DESC;
```

la primer condición indica el numero máximo de días transcurridos y la segunda el numero mínimo.

*Saludos!.*

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, pero no hace lo que necesito.